# C++ “was not declared in this scope” compile error

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and QT, I'm using QT Creator, I created a QT Widget project named nGui, added a QT-QT Designer Form Class named mydlg, I've been trying to create a button in a window, when you click it opens another window while the original windows keeps showing. And here's my codes, but it always show the error: 'my2'was not declared in this scope. I have declared 'my2' in widget.h, and I included the widget.h file in mydlg.cpp, I don't know where is wrong, can someone help me out? Thank you so much!

mydlg.cpp

```
#include "mydlg.h"
#include "ui_mydlg.h"
myDlg::myDlg(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::myDlg)

{
     ui->setupUi(this);
}

myDlg::~myDlg()

{

    delete ui;

}


void myDlg::on_pushButton_clicked()

{

     my2.show();

}
```

widget.h

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H

#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

#include"mydlg.h"

namespace Ui 
{
    class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

    private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    myDlg my2;
    private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
};

 #endif // WIDGET_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

#include "widget.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Title says C, tags and code are C++, now what.

Comment: Oh, and ***do indent.***

Comment: Sorry for the c mistake, I've correct it.

Comment: and also indent thing

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: it's the one in 'mydlg.cpp', line'my2.show()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my2` is declared in the `Widget` class, but you are trying to access it in a member function of the `myDlg` class.

Comment: How can I get the correct access? I'm following a tutorial on QT designer, totally have no idea how to deal with it :(

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with QT. However, the problem you are encountering seems to be regarding C++ scoping rules which have nothing to do with QT. I suggest you learn about the differences between local, global, and class variables and go from there.

Comment: good suggestion, I'll definitely learn about them, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `my2.show()` with `show()`
When you are writing in the `myDlg` class you are writing the behaviour of every object that can be instantiated from that class (including `my2`).

It does not make sense to refer to `my2` within the `MyDlg` class then, since someone else using your class could instead instantiate another object called (for example) `my3` with it instead. What you want to do is tell the compiler when on `_pushButton_clicked()` is called on an object of class `MyDlg` go ahead and call the `show()` function on the same object. You can do this by writing `this->show()` or simply `show()`.